# Scraping data and inputting it into two different tables

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I have scraped the squad data from the following website:
http://www.espnfc.us/club/real-madrid/86/squad

I created a dictionary for each player and i was wondering if I can save the goalkeeper data in a different file than the outfield players data

for now I'm using the following code to input all the data into one output file

Comment: can you show what's inside in your  `data` variable? (at least casillas and any other outfield player)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your data is structured, it's hard to help.

If `data` is a list of dicts, one for each player, with elements describing each column in the web table, you could use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter by position:

```
with open('goalkeepers.json','wb') as goalkeeper_file:
  json.dump(
    [player for player in data if player['POS'] == "G"], 
    goalkeeper_file)

with open('outfielders.json','wb') as outfield_file:
  json.dump(
    [player for player in data if player['POS'] != "G"], 
    outfield_file)
```